# C++ Deleting Node from Linked List

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

I am attempting to remove Nodes from a linked list in an assignment and am encountering an error I have no idea how to solve.

This is my Class

```
class PhoneList
{
public:
    PhoneList(string/*name*/);
    ~PhoneList();
    void showList(ostream&/*file/screen*/) const;
    friend void showList(ostream&/*file/screen*/, PhoneList/*List*/);
    void addDirectory(string/*name*/, int/*areaCode*/, int/*phoneNo*/);
    void removeDirectory(string/*name*/);
    int getNoDirectories()const { return noDirectories; }
    string getTitle()const { return title; }
private:
    Directory *firstPtr;
    string title;
    int noDirectories;
};
```

This is my Directory Struct

```
struct Directory
{
    string name;
    int areaCode;
    int phoneNo;
    Directory *link;
};
```

This is my delete function

```
void PhoneList::removeDirectory(string delName)
{
    Directory *walker = NULL;
    Directory *stalker = NULL;
    Directory *placeHolder = NULL;

    walker = firstPtr;
    stalker = NULL;

    while (walker != NULL)
    {
        if (walker->name == delName)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            stalker = walker;
            walker = walker->link;
        }
    }

    if (walker == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Contact not found. Removal not possible. Please enter valid contact name." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stalker = walker;
        walker = walker->link;
        delete stalker;

        cout << "Contact Deleted." << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is the client code I am using

```
myBlackBook->removeDirectory("Adam Taurus");
myBlackBook->removeDirectory("Xander Rogan");
myBlackBook->removeDirectory("Johnathan Jones");
myBlackBook->removeDirectory("Johnathan Jones");
```

myBlackBook is a Phonelist Object I have created and the three names are in the List and yes the 4th one is a dupe of the 3rd. I need to show that the error message triggers correctly.

I have debugged and the first delete function call goes through correctly but the next time the firstPtr and walker objects show the name member as "Error reading characters of string.".
I have tried multiple ways of fixing this and this keeps happening. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any linked list traversal, you need to test handling the following cases:

1. Adding/removing from an empty list (head pointer is null)
2. Adding/removing on the front of the list (head pointer needs updating)
3. General case of adding/removing from the middle of the list
4. Special case of adding/removing at the end
5. Item searched is not found.

I'm not sure your delete function is handling case #2 above. Otherwise, I'd expect to see code updating `firstPtr` when the head of the list is removed.

```
void PhoneList::removeDirectory(const string& delName)
{
    Directory *walker = firstPtr;
    Directory* previous = NULL;
    bool found = false;

    if (firstPtr)
    {
        while (walker && !found)
        {
            if (walker->name == delName)
            {
                if (walker == firstPtr)
                {
                    // handle the special case of deleting from the front
                    firstPtr = firstPtr->link;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous->link = walker->link;
                }
                delete walker;
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                previous = walker;
                walker = walker->link;
            }
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
         cout << "Contact Deleted." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         cout << "Contact not found." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The bool is not necessary as the first time I run the function it works fine. However even with making firstPtr = firstPtr->link when it runs the second time firstPtr has the "error reading characters of string" value.

Comment: I suspect if your delete function is missing the edge cases, your insert functions might be corrupting the list too.

Comment: *"However even with making firstPtr = firstPtr->link when it runs the second time..*"  That's because the contents of **firstPtr** are already corrupted because you deleted it in the first run.

Comment: Added a check that firstPtr at the beginning was not NULL and made it change firstPtr only if walker = firstPtr and change stalker link to walker link if it wasn't and it runs correctly now. Thank you. your help allowed me to get this. Also that should have read that I made firstPtr = firstPtr->link the first time then the function ran a second time where I encountered the problem. sorry for the confusion